# Handling multiple clicks by mistake from server side

Tags: node.js, redis

Now, I'm working on a bank transactions like app, when a user click multiple  clicks on making a certain transaction we I must accept only the first one and ignore the others for certain time if the transaction has the same parameters.

I was thinking of cache something in redis with the user_id and the params of the transaction .. and check on it before making any transaction, is this is the best way to do that or there are any better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

> Use **throttling** on the client side javascript.

You can throttle your submit button handler. It's like the submit handler would run only on the first click and then would re-run only after a provided amount of time has passed no matter how many times the user would click the submit button in that time. [Here](https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf) is a very nice article on *Throttling and Debouncing* in JavaScript.

Comment: I tried to look on throttling handlers, what I found is throttling in general, what I wanted to do is throttling in case of the same request only, if the request has different params even from the same user I will accept that, did I got u right ?

Comment: Why are you even sending the request to the server if it's from the same user with the same parameter? You can just make sure on the client side that the request would only be sent to the server if there are different parameters passed. And all this logic can be implemented in your throttle function.